# My package not found with render-rmarkdown github action

Tags: r, r-markdown, github-actions, r-package

I'm building an R package and trying to use github actions to do CI and build a website with **pkgdown**.

I used the action template yaml from r-lib [`render-rmarkdown`](https://github.com/r-lib/actions/blob/v2/examples/render-rmarkdown.yaml), but didn't want to deal with **renv** which has been a headache in the past.

I was pretty confident that replacing
`- uses: r-lib/actions/setup-renv@v2` with `- uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v2` would get me there but then I had a bizarre error:

`! there is no package called <my_package>`. What did I need to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [workflow template documentation](https://github.com/r-lib/actions/tree/v2/setup-r-dependencies#installing-the-local-package), I needed to add

```
   - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v2
        with:
          extra-pacakges: local::.
```

This triggers installation of <my_package> before trying to render the .rmd into .md files on github.